# Issue in redshift unload

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-iam

I'm getting the below error while unloading the data from Redshift table

```
unload ('select * from tablename')
to 's3://bucketname/'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/rolename';

ERROR:  User arn:aws:redshift:eu-west-1:123456789012:dbuser:dbaname/dbusername is not authorized to assume IAM Role arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/rolename
DETAIL:
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  User arn:aws:redshift:eu-west-1:123456789012:dbuser:dbname/dbusername is not authorized to assume IAM Role arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/rolename
  code:      8001
  context:   IAM Role=arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/rolename
  query:     0
  location:  xen_aws_credentials_mgr.cpp:238
  process:   padbmaster [pid=3203]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

I use switch role to connect from one account to the other with rolename, the role is having complete access on AWS

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the problems which I resolved to fix this issue.

1. The role attached to the Redshift cluster was different from the role used in the Unload command.
2. The role attached to Redshift was not having only the Read access on S3.

Fixed the above issues and now can be able to Unload data from redshift to S3.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I created a new Role for Redshift. Steps are outlined below

1. Go to IAM Management in AWS Console
2. Create Role- And choose Redshift as the service
3. In the use case select- Redshift - Customizable
4. From the policy choose- AmazonS3FullAccess
5. Give relevant Role Name and Description

Use the IAM Role from the newly created role.